# PHP while loop not executing

Tags: php

My While loop in the code below is not functioning. When i comment out the while line and the two brackets, everything inside the while loop echos fine. As soon as i uncomment the while loop and run it again, i get no errors but all the echos inside disappear.

```
case 'search':

echo "searching".$firstname;


$sqlsearch="SELECT * FROM Customer WHERE firstname='$firstname'";

$sim = mysql_query($conndb, $sqlsearch);

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sim))
{
echo "firstname: ".$row['firstname']."<br>";
echo "lastname: ".$row['lastname']."<br>";  
echo "phone: ".$row['phone']."<br>";
echo "address: ".$row['address']."<br>";
echo "city: ".$row['city']."<br>";
echo "state: ".$row['state']."<br>";
echo "zip: ".$row['zip']."<br>";
echo $sqlsearch;
}

echo "<br>";
echo "seaching 2";
break;
```

Comment: does the `echo $firstname` produce anything?

Comment: No, nothing inside the while loop executes unless you comment out the while portion.

Comment: The bit above all that, your 2nd line in the code above. ie does `$firstname` hold any value before it hits the query?

Comment: Just a note, `mysql_*` functions are deprecated. You should use the newer `mysqli` functions or `PDO`.

Comment: @SamT They're not explicitly depreciated, they're "depreciated as of PHP 5.5.0"

Comment: Yes james, $firstname does hold a value, i have it echoed above the while loop and it outputs correctly

Comment: OK @SamSquanch found the error, i changed the = to == in the while statement and it worked immediately, although now its looping and wont stop

Comment: @user519670 that is wrong, it should still be a single = as you want to assign the result to $row and not compare it. See the manual for examples of how to use it http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-array.php

Answer (score -1):

To fix the issue, i had to change the line while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sim))  to  while($row == mysql_fetch_array($sim))